# How can I remove comma separated same values from list using c# linq

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have a c# Product list:

```
var mylist = new List<Person>{
   new Product{Id=1, Name="p-1", Colors="1,2"},
   new Product{Id=2, Name="p-2", Colors="2,1"},
   new Product{Id=3, Name="p-2", Colors="3,4,5"},
   new Product{Id=4, Name="p-2", Colors="4,5,3"}
}
```

If a product color "1,2" and another product colors is "2,1", these products are same colors. So I want to remove one of them (which doesn't matter). The final list will be like this:

```
var mylist = new List<Person>{
   new Product{Id=1, Name="p-1", Colors="1,2"},
   new Product{Id=3, Name="p-2", Colors="3,4,5"}
}
```

I could not remove same color products from list using c# linq. How can I do this?

Comment: If they are different products why would you remove either?

Comment: It is not important, I want to eleminate the temp list.

Comment: Why on earth are you using comma separated strings for this? Use an array/List of ints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split and sort the Colors, group by them and since you are saying it is not important which might get the first from each group (I assume List was a typo):

```
var mylist = new List<Product>{
    new Product{Id=1, Name="p-1", Colors="1,2"},
    new Product{Id=2, Name="p-2", Colors="2,1"},
    new Product{Id=3, Name="p-2", Colors="3,4,5"},
    new Product{Id=4, Name="p-2", Colors="4,5,3"}
    };

var result = mylist
    .GroupBy(m => string.Join(",",m.Colors.Split(',').Select(c => c.Trim()).OrderBy(c => c)))
    .Select(m => new Product {
        Id=m.First().Id, 
        Name=m.First().Name, 
        Colors=m.Key});
```

Comment: Although the sample code doesn't have any whitespace it may be worth adding a `Trim` in just in case the final list is more like `1, 2`.

Answer (score 0):

I added one property of `string[]` type in the person class to keep it simple. These comma separated values are of no use so this property will be useful in further processing as well.

```
        var persons = new List<Person>{
                                       new Person{Id=1, Name="p-1", Colors="1,2"},
                                       new Person{Id=2, Name="p-2", Colors="2,1"},
                                       new Person{Id=3, Name="p-2", Colors="3,4,5"},
                                       new Person{Id=4, Name="p-2", Colors="4,5,3"}
                                    };

        persons.ForEach(x => x.ColorList = x.Colors.Split(','));

        var distinctPerson = new List<Person>();
        foreach (var item in persons)
        {
            var isExist = distinctPerson.Any(x => x.ColorList.Intersect(item.ColorList).Any());
            if(!isExist)
            {
                distinctPerson.Add(item);
            }
        }
```